# Weak LLN for U-Statistics

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

**Question**

> Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be an i.i.d sequence of random varaibles such that $EX_1=\mu$ and $\sigma^2=\text{Var}(X_1)<\infty$. Then
>   $$
> U_n=\binom{n}{2}^{-1}\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n} X_iX_j\to\mu^2
> $$
>   in probability as $n\to \infty$.

**My attempt**

I was able to prove this claim in the case that $\mu=0$. Indeed in that case we can use Chebeshev's inequality to deduce that
$$
P(|U_n|>\varepsilon)\leq \frac{n(n-1)\sigma^4}{2\varepsilon^2\binom{n}{2}^2}\to 0
$$
as $n\to \infty$ for each $\varepsilon>0$.

**Problem**

I am having difficulty proving the claim when the random variables are not centered. I tried to applied Chebeshev in general, since
$$
EU_n=\frac{2}{n(n-1)}\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\mu^2=2\mu^2
$$
but I am unable to compute the variance of $U_n$ fully. I know that
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(U_n)&=\binom{n}{2}^{-2}\text{Cov}\left(\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n }X_i X_j, \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n} X_i X_j\right)\\
&=\binom{n}{2}^{-2}\left(\binom{n}{2}(2\mu^{2}\sigma^{2}+\sigma^4)+\dotsb\right).
\end{align}
$$
The term in the sum represents covariance of the form $\text{Cov}(X_iX_j, X_jX_i)$. All covariances of the form $$\text{Cov}(X_iX_j, X_kX_l)$$ with $i,j,k, l$ distinct will contribute zero. I am having trouble with counting and computing covariances of the form $$\text{Cov}(X_iX_j, X_kX_l)$$ where exactly one of $k$ or $l$ is $i$ or $j$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the expectation, it should be$$
EU_n=\frac{2}{n(n-1)}\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\mu^2=\mu^2
$$

We first compute

\begin{align}
Cov(X_1X_2,X_1X_2) &=E(X_1^2X_2^2)-E(X_1X_2)^2\\
&=(\sigma^2+\mu^2)^2 - \mu^4\\
&= \sigma^4+2\sigma^2\mu^2
\end{align}

We also have

\begin{align}
Cov(X_1X_2,X_2X_3) &=E(X_1X_2^2X_3)-E(X_1X_2)E(X_2X_3)\\
&=\mu^2(\sigma^2+\mu^2) - \mu^4\\
&= \sigma^2\mu^2
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
Cov(X_1X_2,X_3X_4) &=E(X_1X_2X_3X_4)-E(X_1X_2)E(X_3X_4)\\
&=0
\end{align}

Hence, we just need to compute those terms that involve overlapping index. For the first case, there are $\binom{n}{2}$ of them and for the second case, there are $2n \cdot \binom{n-1}2 $ of them.

$$Pr(|U_n-\mu^2|> \epsilon) \le \frac{\binom{n}2(\sigma^4+2\sigma^2\mu^2) + 2n \cdot \binom{n-1}2(\sigma^2\mu^2)}{\binom{n}{2}^2\epsilon^2}$$

Notice the magnitude of the denominator is of order $n^4$ and the magnitude of the numerator is of order $n^3$.

Hence $U_n$ converges in probability to $\mu^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The different solution to the original problem suggests itself in addition to the brilliant answer from [Siong Thye Goh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/306553/siong-thye-goh). It does not use Chebyshev's inequality, but only the LLN and properties of convergence in probability.

LLN implies that 
$$
\left(\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{n}\right)^2 \xrightarrow{p} \mu^2.
$$
And 
$$
\left(\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{n}\right)^2 = \frac{X_1^2+\ldots+X_n^2}{n^2} + U_n \frac{n-1}{n}.
$$
The first summand in r.h.s. tends to zero in probability: 
$$
\frac{X_1^2+\ldots+X_n^2}{n^2} =\frac1n \cdot \frac{X_1^2+\ldots+X_n^2}{n} \xrightarrow{p} 0 \cdot (\mu^2+ \sigma^2) = 0.
$$
Therefore, 
$$
U_n = \frac{n}{n-1}\left(\left(\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{n}\right)^2 - \frac{X_1^2+\ldots+X_n^2}{n^2}\right)\xrightarrow{p} 1\cdot (\mu^2-0)=\mu^2.
$$